# ¿Porque me muestra registros duplicados?

Tags: php, mysql, sql, base-de-datos, phpmyadmin

soy nuevo en sql y tengo una duda respecto a una consulta que estoy intentando realizar, lo que sucede es que la siguiente consulta me **arroja registros duplicados**:

```
SELECT DISTINCT * 
FROM propiedad 
  INNER JOIN tiene_2 
    ON tiene_2.id_propiedad=propiedad.id_propiedad 
  INNER JOIN universidad 
    ON universidad.id_universidad=tiene_2.id_universidad 
WHERE nombre_universidad 
  LIKE '%u%';
```

(Para poner en contexto, esa consulta corresponde a una búsqueda en la base de datos)

Al insertar esa consulta, en phpmyadmin me arroja los siguientes resultados duplicados:
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Mi tabla en la base de datos es la siguiente:
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Agradecería si pudieran orientarme, muchas gracias.

Comment: Buenas @Crisandru, te iba a comentar que los resultados no están duplicados, fijate en los resultados en el atributo id_universidad, en todos los resultados es diferente, la consulta te está devolviendo bien, si le quitas ese atributo de los resultados de la consulta y todos los que en realidad no necesitas, te dejará de duplicar... Tampoco sabemos si necesitas esos atributos o no... pero lo que está claro que en esa consulta los registros no son duplicados. **Consejo:** Si haces un `SELECT DISTINCT *`, el * significa que quieres todos los campos... tal vez no quieras todos.

Answer (score 1):

Crisandru, cambia tu query por esta y mira se sale bien.
No he logrado exito en encontrar la duplicidad.
He cambiado la consulta para que se haga mas clara.
Entonces:
Tabla - Propiedade tiene un apellido (P)
Tabla - Tiene_2  tiene un apellido (t2)
Tabla - universida tiene un apellido (u)

Haga una prueba e vea se sale duplicidad aun.

```
SELECT DISTINCT 
p.id_propiedad,p.sector_propiedad,p.descripcion,p.precio_arriendo,
p.tipo_propiedad,p.cantidad_banos,p.cantidad_habitaciones,
p.amoblado,p.superficie_tota,p.estacionamiento,p.gastos_comunes,
p.servicio_aseo,p.imagenes_propriedad,u.id_universidad,u.nombre_universidad 
FROM propiedad p
INNER JOIN tiene_2 t2 ON P.id_propiedad = t2.id_propiedad
INNER JOIN universidad u ON t2.id_universidad u.id_universidad
WHERE u.nombre_universidad LIKE '%u%';
```

Comment: La pregunta fue *"Por qué me salen registros duplicados?"*. Las respuestas de sólo código no proveen tanto valor sin una explicación que le acompañe. Lo mejor es explicarle a OP por qué sucede, así no le ocurrirá nuevamente en el futuro

Comment: @Arriel parece que ya ha añadido la explicación :-)

Comment: Lo que le sucede es que ha hecho un `SELECT DISTINCT *` y **no hay duplicados**, fijate bien en sus resultados... el id_universidad no se duplica ni una vez, no hay registros duplicados, simplemente es que  ha seleccionado todo, pero tampoco sabemos qué atributos necesita

Answer (score 0):

es por los registros que tenes tenes una universidad con muchas propiedades, al usar DISTINCT le decis que no repita lineas completas, si limitas las columnas que pedis vas a lograr que no se repitan, en caso de necesitar usar todos los datos tendrias que usar un GROUP BY por los datos que pueden variar. cualquier duda me consultas